# How to save 3 dimensional array in to csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I had train a model which has 3 number of classes .Now i want to save the prediction in csv file its throwing me an error data must be 1 dimensional .

```
prediction1= loaded_model.predict(X_test,verbose=1)
prediction1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "phrase": test["Phrase"],
    "predict":prediction1
})
[output] Erorr
Data must be 1-dimensional

print(prediction1)
[[0.2634249  0.27810773 0.45846733]
[0.2634249  0.27810773 0.45846733]
[0.2634249  0.27810773 0.45846733]
...
[0.2634249  0.27810773 0.45846733]
[0.2634249  0.27810773 0.45846733]
[0.2634249  0.27810773 0.45846733]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` and `numpy`, it can resolve your problem by reshaping the array and saving it into csv

Like this 2 Dimensional:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10).reshape((2,5))
np.savetxt('save.txt', x)
```

So, for 3 Dimensional workaround will be:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd    
x = np.arange(60).reshape((2,5,6))
with file('test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for slice_2d in x:
        np.savetxt(outfile, slice_2d)
```

You can also use `pickle` and [numpy.ndarray.tofile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile)

Hope it helps

Thanks

Comment: it's just a file name, you can give according to yours

Comment: yeah the `test.txt` is the file name but did you mean `open`? because using `file` says `file` is not found in python 3.9.5?

Comment: yes, for me it's working fine, check the file path where it's getting stored.

Comment: interesting. it looks like its not about the file path because it has an issue with  `file` function itself; PyLance cannot find any `file` function and suggests to make it `FileIO` or `FileDescriptor`. The function call `open` works for the same file path. Possibly related with Python versions or environment.

Answer (score 0):

@mcy

Yes, the second part of @Avinash Singh's code should replace `file` with `open` and thus read:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for slice_2d in x:
        np.savetxt(outfile, slice_2d)
```

However, I would strongly recommend considering saving your file with the .npy extension if possible. `np.save()` is incredibly faster and allows easier reloading of files into numpy arrays. Just be sure to document the format of your saved data carefully since you can't rely on the nice DataFrame column labels ;)